# Is it valid to have a span tag inside i tag?

Tags: html

```
<i class='hovicon effect-1 sub-a'>
    <div class='menu__items' style='background-image:url(".$iconURL.");' data-supercategoryid='5'></div>
</i>
```

In the above code,  as per the W3C validations, it gives an error while validating the site according to W3C standards.

**The error is as follows:**

> *Like **div** tag is not allowed as child of element **i** tag.*

Is it a valid way to have a `<span>` tag inside an `<i>` tag?

Comment: Why cant you try the same way you tried for `div` tag? It might give the required answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is valid to have a `<span>` tag as the content of an `<i>` tag. However, it is **not** valid to have a `<div>` tag as the content of an `<i>` tag.

See the MDN docs for `<i>` tag [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i).

> Permitted content :   Phrasing content.
>
> Tag omission :    None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.
>
> Permitted parents :   Any element that accepts phrasing content.

The brief excerpt above from the MDN docs shows the permitted content for `<i>` tag as **Phrasing content**.

See relevant sections of the [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) docs below.

> Phrasing content defines the text and the mark-up it contains. Runs of phrasing content make up paragraphs.
>
> Elements belonging to this category are `<abbr>, <audio>, <b>, <bdo>, <br>, <button>, <canvas>, <cite>, <code>, <command>, <data>, <datalist>, <dfn>, <em>, <embed>, <i>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <kbd>, <keygen>, <label>, <mark>, <math>, <meter>, <noscript>, <object>, <output>, <progress>, <q>, <ruby>, <samp>, <script>, <select>, <small>, <span>, <strong>, <sub>, <sup>, <svg>, <textarea>, <time>, <var>, <video>, <wbr>` and plain text (not only consisting of white spaces characters).
>
> A few other elements belong to this category, but only if a specific condition is fulfilled:
>
> - `<a>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<area>`, if it is a descendant of a  element
> - `<del>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<ins>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<link>`, if the itemprop attribute is present
> - `<map>`, if it contains only phrasing content
> - `<meta>`, if the itemprop attribute is present